# How to Resize a Barcode?

Tags: c#, barcode

I created a tool that generates PDF417 2D barcodes. The output png file is 290x78 pixels.

The reason behind this width and height is a formula used to create this symbol so that it is correctly read by bar code scanners.

My symbol is 13 columns and 39 rows.

This formula is:

```
Width = ((17 * # of columns) + 69) X + 2 (size of quiet zone)
Height = (# of rows) (row height) + 2 (size of quiet zone)
```

So:

```
17 * 13 + 69 = 290px
39 * 2 = 78px
```

My question is the software I use to create these bar codes allows you to save the file to this size but prints it at a different size.

These print parameters turn out to be as follow but I cannot figure out how to calculate them:

```
X Dimension (in)       :0.0067
Y Dimension (in)       :0.0133
Height x Width (in)    :0.52 x 1.93
Height x Width (mm)    :13.21 x 49.11
Rows x Columns         : 39 x 13   
Error Correction Level :5
Bytes Encoded          :257
SLD Codeword           :1
Data Codewords         :157
Pad Codewords          :285
MPDF Codewords         :0
EC Codewords           :64
Total Codewords        :507
```

Here's a snapshot of the program I currently use:

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: not sure what the problem is, but how about asking the software author abut this?

Comment: There is no problem. The solution is mathematics. How does 290px print at 1.93 inches and 78px print at 0.52 inches is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue of DPI and print size.

```
pixels/dpi=inches
```

or if you're going the other way

```
inches x dpi = pixels
```

You can set the DPI dropdown in your software to the necessary value.

See this calculator to play with the values: http://auctionrepair.com/pixels.html

Comment: Got it. (290/300)*2 = 1.93in // (78/300)*2 = 0.52in

Comment: Glad it worked. It's weird that you have to multiply by 2 to get the correct value. I suspect maybe the printer is printing at 150dpi, which is causing the values to be off by two?